# Visual Studio Intellisense for Typescript not working on mac

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, intellisense

I am trying to find out a way so that my Intellisense for Typescript works as same as in Windows. I am using macbook pro m1. If I write any typescript code, instead of showing import options, it just shows as "any" for the item. Please help me with this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI899.png)

Comment: Do you got any solutions for this? I'm facing the same issue as well.